# jQuery dynamically generated radio buttons then value is passed to continue button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, jquery-events

I have a page that receives a JSON response.  If there is more than one option in the JSON it will dynamically generate some radio buttons using a for loop in Javascript based on the greater length.

Something like:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i ++){
    alert(i);
        //draw the HTML radio buttons based on the data i++
    }
        //value from radio button button gets passed to a continue button
```

What would be the best way to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
for ( var i in json ) {
   var input = $('<input>', { 
     type: 'radio', name: 'group-name', 
     value: json[i], 
     'class': 'my_radio'
   } );
   $('body').append( input );
}

$('#continue').click( function() {
    var selected = null;
    $('input.my_radio').each( function() {
         if ( $(this).attr( 'selected' ) )
             selected = $(this).val();
    });
    // do something with selected....
});
```

You'll have to surround it with a form element if you need that.  I haven't tested this, by the way.